# Based on a pattern to print next line along with the above pattern in python

Tags: python, perl, unix

I have come across a problem in python whether I need to perform the below task.

1. I need to look for a pattern in a line from 11th position till 13th position whether it is 004 or 008.
2. If the above match is successes I need to print the data from 13th position till 18th position and along with that I need to print next line.

Input Data:

```
CH0012012300123476
CH0012012300423458
BXXXXXXX
CH0012012300823987
AXXXXXXX
CH0012012300523234
```

Output:

```
423458BXXXXXXX
823987AXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. And what did you try and what does not work with your attempt? Please post your code, too, so that people can help finding errors or optimizing it. See also [ask] and [mcve] Besides that: is your input data stored in a file? Do you want to read it from a file? Btw: please mark data like code by indenting by 4 spaces for readability.

Comment: Why is this tagged [perl]? Where does Perl come into play in your question?

Comment: I have the option to write the code either in Python or Perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can just make an iterator over your lines and use `next` to get the next line if needed. Since this will forward the same iterator being iterated over, the BIC will not be read by the `for` loop in that case.

```
s = """CH0012012300123476
CH0012012300423458
BXXXXXXX
CH0012012300823987
AXXXXXXX
CH0012012300523234"""

it = iter(s.splitlines())
for line in it:
    if line[10:13] in ["004", "008"]:
        print(line[12:] + next(it))
# 423458BXXXXXXX
# 823987AXXXXXXX
```

Note that while `line[10]` could raise an `IndexError` if the line has less than 11 characters, the slicing will just return an empty slice.

---

Iterating over a file provides access to an iterator over the lines (including their newline characters):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[10:12] == '00' and line[12] in '48':
            print(line[12:18], next(f), sep='')
```

But in the end it's the same thing as above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.    My source is a file and reading the data from the same checking for the pattern in each line.